# EventMachine not receiving TCP data on localhost

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

Using [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) gem i am trying to send and receive data on localhost. Following is the code of my client and server files.

**server.rb**

```
class BCCServer < EM::Connection
    attr_accessor :server_socket

    def post_init
        puts "BCC Server"
    end

    def recieve_data(data)
        puts "Received data: #{data}"   

        send_data "You sent: #{data}"
    end

end

EM.run do
  EM.start_server("0.0.0.0", 3000, BCCServer)
end
```

**client.rb**

```
class DCClient < EventMachine::Connection
  def post_init
    puts "Sending "
    send_data "send data"
    close_connection_after_writing 
  end

  def receive_data(data)
    puts "Received #{data.length} bytes"
  end

  def unbind
    puts 'Connection Lost !'
  end
end

EventMachine.run do
  EventMachine::connect("127.0.0.1", 3000, DCClient)
end
```

I executed both server and client files in separate console. Following is the output of client

**Client output**

```
Sending 
Connection Lost !
```

**Server output**

```
BCC Server
............>>>10
```

In the server file i have printed the data received but its showing "............>>>10". Where i am doing the mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look at the EM::Connection implementation

https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/connection.rb

```
def receive_data data
  puts "............>>>#{data.length}"
end
```

Method receive_data returns exactly what you are experiencing.
That means original method gets called and not yours. That means one thing. You have a typo in a method which you tried to override :)

In BCCServer you have

```
recieve_data(data)
```

instead of

```
receive_data(data)
```

Comment: Yes, its a typo in server file. Thanks